# Visual Studio Cordova App, can't run debugger - Could not locate the appxrecipe file

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, typescript

If I create a brand new Cordova project (JavaScript or TypeScript) and try to debug on Ripple or on the local machine I get an error during build that says "Could not locate the appxrecipe file."

I googled it and nothing comes up. What is this file and how does it get generated? Shouldn't it be generated when I create the project?

I've already lost an entire day to this, running repairs on visual studio and trying things that had no effect. Frustrating!

Comment: I don't know anything about this appxrecipe file.  Never heard of it. And I don't see it as part of my Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova project.

What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: VS 2015 Community. Perhaps it is a file from WinJS or Cordova. Did you look in your bld/Android/Debug folder?

Comment: When I create a universal app I get an appxrecipe file in /bin/x64/debug folder. So, it seems it must be something with the auto-project creation process that is not creating the file in the case of cordova projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a while to figure out but it seems that the version of node.js that would get installed with Visual Studio was too old (0.10.x). When I installed the x64 version of node.js from the node website, it installed a 64 bit version which also wouldn't work with Cordova in Visual Studio.

The answer was to install the 32bit version of node.js (node-v5.1.0-x86.msi) available from their website. Now everything compiles correctly!

Comment: I suppose you could not install both versions next to each other?

Answer (score 0):

I was also stucked with the issue but my problem was little bit different. I wanted to build a project for Windows 10 Mobile platform.

It was really weird because everytime when I tried to build a project from CLI with *ionic build windows*, the build was successul. But it had been throwing the error about **appxrecipe file** while building with Visual Studio again and again.

Then I noticed that everytime I open a project in Visual Studio (2015, Community Edition) there is one change when you open your confix.xml file in Visual Studio editor - the change was that Windows Target Version was set to 8.1 again. I tried to change it to Windows 10 again, save it and build but the error was still there.

I have solved it with installation of Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile and it works like a charm now. Maybe this information could be helpful for somebody...

Comment: Ok, one more information. It also occures when you build your app with CLI (cordova build windows | ionic build windows) and then you want to run it with Visual Studio. When you build it with CLI, you never ever run it with VS and you will get appxrecipe file error.